# Jquery mobile - problems with height

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

After trying different things I go to the last option that is, asking for help, I have 3 problems that I can't solve by myself, I have a webapp designed in the future for phonegap with the following bug:

1) The panels aren't shown correctly, for some reason they are taking the height of the content inconrrectly and a black are is shown behind bug 3. For that I'm using the following "hacks"

[image]

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page {
    min-height:100%!important;
/* min. height for modern browser */
    height:auto!important;
/* important rule for modern Browser */
    height:100%!important;
/* min. height for IE */
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0
}
```

I have done a jsfiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/tronne/bLhmdacu/

Could you kindly help me?

Thanks

Comment: I am still not 100% sure what you are asking, can you specifically express the bugs and what the desired look is?

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry, I might have explained myself wrongly. I did a screenshot to better show the problem. I hope it's clear now. Thanks!

Comment: In the mean time I've deleted all the code above, and apparently it's working, I dont understand :s the only issue is when I do this, the fixed panel from the "chat" tab is not showing till I click the panel, after the panel is shown, no problems. BTW I'm using android, in blackberry it's ok and in the desktop as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qjtcfrsk/show

Comment: Why not set the background-color of the container that is holding your right column? And if you're setting it to 100% height, the container needs the height set as well. 100% of nothing doesn't mean anything.